# Importing data from one table to another under conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help on how to proceed with this problem :

I have the following **SQL Server** tables :

**`Transitions`**

---

`ID` *int*,
`VariableID` *int*,
`To_VariableID` *int*,
`To_ValueID` *int*,
`To_CommentInput` *bit*,
`To_SP` *varchar*(255)

---

**`Processes`**

---

`ID` *int*,
`VariableID` *int*,
`ValueID` *int*,
`Manual_Value` *varchar*(255)

---

> What applies for **`Transitions`**: Only one field among
>
> `To_VariableID`, `To_ValueID`, `To_CommentInput`, `To_SP`
>
> can be set at a time in each row.
>   
>   In some cases I want certain data from **`Transitions`** to go to **`Processes`**.

Now, if `To_ValueID` has been set in a row in **`Transitions`**, its value should go to the `ValueID` field in the **`Processes`** table.
If not, then the field that is filled ( don't know which one, it could be `To_VariableID`, `To_CommentInput`, `To_SP` ) should go in the `Manual_Value` field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming values are null if not there `Coalesce(To_ValueID, ToVariableID, To_CommentInput, To_SP)`

Comment: Yes, other values are always null.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you put some example data in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, although your exact mapping may differ.

```
Insert Into Processes (Id, VariableID, ValueID, Manual_Value)
Select
  Id,
  VariableID,
  To_ValueID,
  Coalesce(To_VariableID, To_CommentInput, To_SP)
From
  Transistions
```

Comment: This query assumes `To_ValueID` will always be NOT NULL which is not true. `To_ValueID` should be copied to `ValueID` only if it is NOT NULL.

Comment: And what should go into ValueID if it is null?

Comment: So If it isn't null it inserts it, which is correct, and if it is null, it inserts it, which is also correct?

Comment: Thank you. Seems perfect now.